# rosserial connection not working with custom messages! [SOLVED]

Tags: ros, arduino, messages, rosserial

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi community!

I've got a problem, as the title suggests, with my custom messages used in arduino.

I publish here the arduino code and explain later:

```
#include <pkg1/Num.h>
#include <ros.h>
#include <std_msgs/String.h>


ros::NodeHandle  nh;

pkg1::Num type_Num;
std_msgs::String str_msg;

ros::Publisher chatter("chatter", &str_msg);
ros::Publisher PUB2("newmessage", &type_Num);

char hello[20]= "hello world";
int counter=0;

void setup()
{
  nh.initNode();
  nh.advertise(chatter);
}

void loop()
{
  type_Num.first_name = "danielooow";
  type_Num.last_name = "gonsaleeesss";
  type_Num.score = counter;
  PUB2.publish( &type_Num );
  str_msg.data = hello;
  chatter.publish( &str_msg );
  nh.spinOnce();
  counter++;
  delay(100);
}
```

As you see, the code is only an expansion of the HelloWorld example of ros_lib.

It compiles perfectly.

Once uploaded to my Arduino UNO, I call the rosserial connection:

```
~/catkin_ws$ rosrun rosserial_python serial_node.py _port:=/dev/ttyACM0
```

And i get this error:

```
    [INFO] [WallTime: 1458399926.066204] ROS Serial Python Node
    [INFO] [WallTime: 1458399926.072844] Connecting to /dev/ttyACM0 at 57600 baud
    [ERROR] [WallTime: 1458399943.176784] Unable to sync with device; possible link problem or link software version mismatch such as hydro rosserial_python with groovy Arduino
```

The thing is, **when I upload the HelloWorld example, the connection works!!** and the chatter topic is properly registered in the ROS master, **but when I use the new code, it doesn't** .

I just don't know what's going on here.

Thoughts:

- I thought it could be a `delay` problem but removing the delay in the code hasn't made anything.
- I also thought that maybe in the creation of the custom message there's a problem (something related with the   CMakeLists.txt or the pakage.xml) but the message can be used in a normal non-arduino code, registering successfully in the ROS master and all that stuff, so that makes me doubt about it.
- It's maybe that i have to use a second Node Handle??

For possible answers regarding using `#define USE_USBCON` -> i've already tried that and then the compiler says something about it requires the `iostream` library --> i just don't think that is the way to go for solving this (maybe i'm wrong i don't know..).

Thanks to everyone in advance. I would appreciate a detailed answer.

---

**SOLVED!!! LOOK AT THE ANSWERS!**

---

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/229600/rosserial-connection-not-working-with-custom-messages!-%5Bsolved%5D/) by [thepirate16](https://answers.ros.org/users/26128/thepirate16/) on ROS Answers with karma: 101 on 2016-03-19

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

SOLVED!!!!!!

It was a novice error! **I JUST HAD TO ADVERTISE THE PUBLISHER!!!!**

```
  nh.advertise(PUB2);
```

Everything is working now!

Thanks anyway, you're great guys.

Can someone mark the answer as the correct one? I can't due to my lack of points. Thanks.

---

Originally posted by [thepirate16](https://answers.ros.org/users/26128/thepirate16/) with karma: 101 on 2016-03-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1